# Javascript does there is a nice way to 'slice' a map

Tags: javascript

I'm aware of `slice()` for arrays, right now to 'slice' a map I am using this code :

```
const map = new Map([[1,"a"],[2,"b"]])

var arrayTmp = Array.from(map).slice(0,1);

var myMap = new Map();
arrayTmp.forEach(value => {
   myMap.set(value[0], value[1]); 
});
```

It works correctly, but I was wondering if there was some existing native  methods to get a more concise code?

Comment: Keys in Map should be unordered - how do you going to slice it?

Comment: @RidgeA think you are thinking of an object not a Map, maps are ordered: "The Map object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original insertion order of the keys." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Would an array not work better here? Maps aren't indexed so slicing will mean a fair amount of iteration, I think

Comment: @atmd [object keys are ordered in ES6+](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/)

Comment: @atmd, yeah, MDN says so. But specification - don't http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-map-objects. I think specification has precedence.

Comment: @atmd, yes, it looks like Map (as well as Set) should keep entries in insertion order - https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map.prototype.foreach
TIL :-)

Comment: @RidgeA the specifications do not say "store the insertion order of keys" *at the top*, however, if you check the `.forEach` section iteration is explicitly described as happening in insertion order. Moreover, further down for `.set`, the steps also explicitly say that the new entry should the the *last* one in `List`, which describes the contents of the Map.

Comment: @VLAZ, yeah, already found, see my comment right above :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) stores the key/value pairs in insertation order.

You could omit the iteration and take just the sliced array as parameter for the constructor.

```js
const
    map = new Map([[1, "a"], [2, "b"]]);
    arrayTmp = Array.from(map).slice(0, 1),
    myMap = new Map(arrayTmp),

console.log([...myMap]);
```